# Выравнивание текста файла по центру

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дан файл в котором текст выровнен по правому краю. Нужно выровнять по центру, с длиной строки 50 символов (в общем, не важно).

Использовал такую конструкцию:

```
filename = input("Введите имя файла: ")
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line_num in range(len(lines)):
        lines[line_num] = '{:^50}'.format(lines[line_num])
with open(filename, 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(lines)
```

После этого текст начинает плясать в разные стороны.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мешает символ перевода строки. Нужно перед выравниванием его убрать и потом опять добавить:

```
lines[line_num] = '{:^50}'.format(lines[line_num].strip()) + "\n"
```

*Увидел, что исходный текст был выровнен по правому краю (я-то проверял на обычном тексте без выравнивания). Тогда наверняка еще выравнивающие пробелы все портили. К счастью, для приведенного решения это неважно, потому что strip() удаляет и пробелы в начале строки.*

Answer (score 0):

На сколько я знаю

```
def center(string, length):
    l1 = (length - len(string))/2
    return '-'*l1 + string + '-'*l1
```

Где length - это ваше 50

Comment: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'